# Setting a limit to a input

Tags: c, if-statement

I actually have it working, but with using two if-statements. I was wondering if there was a better way to set the input limit, and why my one if-statement isn't working.
As I want to set a limit to a number inputted to 1 between 2000.

---

My working code with the two if-statements.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

int num;

printf("Please Enter a number between 1 and 2000\n");
scanf("%d", &num);

if(num > 2000 ){
    printf("Your number isn't between 1 and 2000");
    return 0;
}
if(num <= 0){
    printf("Your number isn't between 1 and 2000");
    return 0;
}

printf("%d", num);
return 0;
}
```

My single if-statement that isn't working

```
if(num > 2000 && num <= 0){
    printf("Your number isn't between 1 and 2000");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No number can be greater than 2000 *and* less than/equal to zero. Do you mean *or*?

Comment: I'm trying to set a number limit to what the user can input.

Comment: Change `&&` to `||`.  It's an error if *either* condition is met.  They can't both be met.  How many numbers can you think of that are both greater than 2000 and less then or equal to zero?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand why is it that my first two if-statements work, but trying to combine them don't?

Comment: That's because `&&` means *and*, not *or*.

Comment: But I want both conditions to apply.

Comment: A do you know what a [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) is?  Try writing one for your logic expression with the following three inputs: 0, 42, 2001.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments section, the expression `num > 2000 && num <= 0` can never be true, as `num` can never be smaller than 1 and larger than 2000 at the same time. Therefore, you probably want to use the `||` (logical OR) operator instead of the `&&` (logical AND) operator in that expression.

Also, it is unsafe to use the result of the function `scanf` without first checking the return value of that function. See this guide for further information: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

I recommend you change your code to the following, which will prompt the user again for input if the previous input was invalid:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    int num;

    for (;;) // infinite loop, equivalent to while(true)
    {
        int retval;

        printf( "Please enter a number between 1 and 2000: " );

        retval = scanf( "%d", &num );

        if ( retval != 1 )
        {
            printf( "error: input failure!\n" );
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        // retval == 1 if we reach this line, so we can
        // be sure that num now contains valid input (which
        // may still be out of range, though)

        if ( 1 <= num && num <= 2000 ) break;

        printf( "The entered number is not in the correct range, please try again.\n" );
    }

    printf( "Your input is in the correct range!\n" );
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

However, the code above has one problem: If you enter a letter instead of a number, then the program will abort with the error message "input failure" instead of asking the user to input another value. This is not easy to fix with the `scanf` function, because calling that function again will cause the function to fail immediately, without waiting for new user input, because it will attempt to read the letters again as a number. A possible workaround would be to consume all input up to and including the newline character `'\n'` (for example using the function `fgetc`) using the line `while ( (c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && c != '\n' ) ;` and then to call `scanf` again.

Alternatively, it may be better to not use `scanf` at all and to use `fgets` and `strtol` instead. See the guide mentioned above for further information on the advantages of using these functions instead of `scanf`.

Using these functions instead, I would recommend the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 100

int main( void )
{
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    long num;

    for (;;) // infinite loop, equivalent to while(true)
    {
        char *p;

        printf( "Please enter a number between 1 and 2000: " );

        p = fgets( buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin );

        if ( p == NULL )
        {
            printf( "error: input failure!\n" );
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        // p != NULL if we reach this line, so we can
        // be sure that buffer now contains valid input (which
        // may still be out of range, though)

        // attempt to convert the string in buffer to a number
        errno = 0;
        num = strtol( buffer, &p, 10 );
        if ( errno != 0 || p == buffer )
        {
            printf( "The entered input is not a valid number, please try again\n" );
            continue;
        }

        // num now contains the converted number, so
        //check whether it is in range
        if ( 1 <= num && num <= 2000 ) break;

        printf( "The entered number is not in the correct range, please try again.\n" );
    }

    printf( "Your input is in the correct range!\n" );
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use any functions/ arrays, but I'm having a hard time understanding why I can't set num to (num > 15462 && num <= 0), sorry I'm new.

Comment: @Patriots_fan: The expression `num > 15462 && num <= 0` consists of two sub-expressions: 1. `num > 15462` and 2. `num <= 0`. Since both sub-expressions are combined by the `&&` (logical AND) operator, the entire expression will only be true if both sub-expressions are true. However, this is never possible. Both of the sub-expressions can be false and one of them can be true, not they can't both be true at the same time. However, if you combine both sub-expressions with the `||` (logical OR) operator instead, then the whole expression is true if at least one of the sub-expressions is true.

Comment: So, can I do this  !( num > 2000 || num <=0)

Comment: In your code, the `if` expression specifies when the user input is to be considered invalid. However, in my code, the `if` expression specifies the opposite, i.e. when the user input is to be considered correct. Therefore, in your code, `num > 2000 || num <=0` would be correct, and in my code, `!( num > 2000 || num <=0)` would be correct. The expression I used, which is `1 <= num && num <= 2000`, is equivalent to `!( num > 2000 || num <=0)`.

Comment: !( num > 2000 || num <=0) isn't working for me now, I just don't get why setting the num to a limit between 2000 to 1 is hard. Should I just keep my two if-statements since they work? Also is using scanf good?

Comment: Are you trying to use the expression `!( num > 2000 || num <=0)` in your code or in my code? As I stated in my previous comment, that expression would only be correct in my code. With your code, you have to invert it by removing the `!`.

Comment: I have now updated my answer with an example without using `scanf`. I really recommend that you read that guide that I linked to in my answer, so that you understand the advantages and disadvantages of using `scanf`.

Comment: Ok, thank you I will look into it and try to learn and understand.

Comment: @Patriots_fan: Also, feel free to ask if you don't understand something about my code. You will probably need to read the documentation on the functions [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) to understand it.